# C++ WINAPI setting window background image doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, background, window

I hate that I have done it before, I feel like I am missing something and I don't know what it is. So, I am trying to set the background image of a windows in C++ WinAPI.

My Resources.rc

```
#include "Resources.h"

BACKGROUND BITMAP "background.bmp"
```

My Resources.h

```
#define BACKGROUND 200
```

My Main.cpp

```
....
WNDCLASSEX wcls;
wcls.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcls.style          = CS_PARENTDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW|CS_DBLCLKS;
wcls.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcls.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcls.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcls.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcls.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(HICON));
wcls.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcls.hbrBackground  = HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wcls.lpszClassName  = L"WndClass";
wcls.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(HICON));

HWND Window = CreateWindowEx (
                             WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
                             wcls.lpszClassName,
                             L"Window Title",
                             WS_VISIBLE|WS_POPUP|WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
                             CW_USEDEFAULT,
                             CW_USEDEFAULT,
                             384,
                             128,
                             NULL,
                             NULL,
                             hInstance,
                             NULL
                             );

if (!Window ) return 0;

SetLayeredWindowAttributes(
                           Window,
                           RGB(35, 35, 35),
                           85,
                           LWA_ALPHA|LWA_COLORKEY
                           );

SetWindowPos(
             Window,
             HWND_TOPMOST,
             0,
             0,
             0,
             0,
             SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOREDRAW|SWP_NOSIZE
             );

ShowWindow(Window, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
UpdateWindow(Window);


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM Wpar, LPARAM Lpar) {
HBITMAP Background = NULL;
BITMAP BgImg;
HDC DeviceContext, BgContext;
PAINTSTRUCT PaintStruct;

switch (Msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:  
         ContextLansator = BeginPaint(hWnd, &PaintStruct);
         Fundal = LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BACKGROUND)); 
         FundalLansator = CreateCompatibleDC(DeviceContext);
         SelectObject(DeviceContext, Background);
         GetObject(Background, sizeof(BgImg), &BgImg);
         BitBlt(DeviceContext, 0, 0, 384, 128, BgContext, 0, 0, SRCAND);
         DeleteObject(Background);
         DeleteDC(BgContext);
         EndPaint(hWnd, &PaintStruct);
    break;
.....
```

I am using Code::Blocks. The resource is embedded correctly, the window starts but just a white background, the image is not painted. The WM_PAINT message is called once, at the beginning. I fill like something is wrong with BgImg but I don't know what. Some help needed! Thanks!

Comment: Um, you're using a lot of uninitialized variables.

Comment: Then the bitmap does not not exist in the module specified by hInstance. Make sure your hInstance is correct and that the resource really is an integer resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a PatternBrush and set it to the background before registering class. For example:

```
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINAPIBACKGROUND));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDB_BITMAP1 ) ) );
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINAPIBACKGROUND);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Bitmap depth shouldn't matter. But take a look at the styles in your implementation.

[image]

Comment: I just get a black background. My bitmap is 24-bits, could that be the problem?

Comment: Which means you are not using the correct identifier for the bitmap from resource file.

Comment: I can't believe I'm wasting my hole day with this #@%&*

Comment: The same happens if I load the bitmap by its name (no MAKEINTRESOURCE but directly the filename)

Comment: Yes, it looks like the problem lies in the bitmap image.

Comment: I used the new version of GIMP (which is the worst of them) and it exported the bitmap with information that the linker cannot understand. Be aware!

Answer (score 1):

i use this code and it work fine for me.
i use code block 4.7 too.

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
    HDC             hdc;
    BITMAP          bitmap;
    HDC             hdcMem;
    HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap;
    hBitmap01 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "c:\\energy.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);


    hdc = BeginPaint(wnd01, &ps);

    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap01);

    GetObject(hBitmap01, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);

    EndPaint(wnd01, &ps);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After 20 hours working on what I think is a similar symptom, I found a solution.

My problem was `bitmap` not loading. I verified the file was truly `bitmap` and code correct. I corrected and recompiled but `Code::Blocks` would not load it (`return = 0`). Try deleting, the two folders `BIN` and `OBJ` and the two files `xxx.depend` and `xxx.layout`. Then recompile and run.